# Android App icon not showing in Mobile Android Market but does on the web

Tags: android

I have a real newbie issue. I have recently uploaded my first android app, Killer Pool Score Card, and I appear to have a problem with my market app icon. The android default icon displays on the mobile site not my own custom one. On the web market place my icon is shown, but there is obviously a problem with this for the mobile site.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this, cheers in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide your own icon in drawable-mdpi and drawable-ldpi for medium/low resolutions. Instead, there is the default icon, probably left-over from the application wizard.

You should at least provide default resolutions (drawable folder) for all your image resources etc.

Otherwise, resources won't load on medium/low resolutions. Nowadays, there is an xhdpi as well.

The Dev Guide on supporting multiple screens should explain the details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: That's great I've fixed it now thanks to you help.  Thanks for the clear and concise response.